# How to convert date strings to timestamp without knowing the date format

Tags: postgresql, timestamp, date-format, bulk-load, postgresql-copy

I am trying to write a query to insert a value into a `timestamp with no timezone data` type field. The value is coming from CSV file.

The version I am working with is **PostgreSQL 8.1.21**.

The CSV file upload is done by the client and it has a date column. The date sometimes comes as `'28-Sep-13'` and sometimes as `'28/09/2013'` formats.

I tried to use the following to cast the string into timestamp:
`str_date::timestamp`.

This works fine if `str_date` is something like `'28-Sep-13'` but it won't work if the incoming date has the format `'28/09/2013'`, when this error occurs:

> ```
> ERROR: date/time field value out of range: "28/09/2013"  
> HINT:  Perhaps you need a different "datestyle" setting
> ```

Basically the client keeps changing the date format in the uploaded CSV file.
Is there a way to convert the date strings into timestamp depending on its actual format?

Comment: First of all: consider upgrading. [PostgreSQL **8.1** was released in 2005 and has reached end of life a year ago](http://wiki.postgresql.org/wiki/PostgreSQL_Release_Support_Policy). It is horribly outdated.

Comment: How nice of you guys to use my birthday as an example ;-)

Answer (score 17, accepted):

You need to set your datestyle to "ISO, DMY".  It is set to "ISO, MDY" by default, and would cause your example to fail:

```
> show datestyle;

 DateStyle 
-----------
 ISO, MDY
(1 row)

> select '28-Sep-13'::date;
    date    
------------
 2013-09-28
(1 row)

> select '28/09/2013'::date;
ERROR:  date/time field value out of range: "28/09/2013"
LINE 1: select '28/09/2013'::date;
               ^
HINT:  Perhaps you need a different "datestyle" setting.

> set datestyle = 'ISO, DMY';
SET

> select '28-Sep-13'::date;
    date    
------------
 2013-09-28
(1 row)

> select '28/09/2013'::date;
    date    
------------
 2013-09-28
(1 row)
```

(examples done in PostgreSQL 9.1, but the DateStyle setting and associated behavior are ancient, so should work fine)

Comment: Thanks Matthew for the help. I added set datestyle = 'ISO, DMY' to the query and problem is solved.

Comment: Glad to hear it fixed the problem.  If you could be so kind as to mark the answer accepted, it would be appreciated!

Answer (score 7):

You can circumvent the problem with these steps:

1. Create an empty **temporary table** with the same structure as target table:

   ```
   CREATE TEMP TABLE tmp AS SELECT * FROM real_tbl LIMIT 0;
   ```
2. Change the **type** of the problematic column to **text**:

   ```
   ALTER TABLE tmp ALTER COLUMN str_date TYPE text;
   ```
3. **Import** data to the temp table. Should work fine now:

   ```
   COPY tmp FROM '/path/to/my/file.txt';
   ```
4. **`INSERT` into target table** depending on depending on the actual content of the column:

   ```
   INSERT INTO real_tbl (col1, col2, col3, date_col)
   SELECT col1, col2, col3
        , CASE WHEN str_date ~~ '%/%'
             THEN to_date(str_date, 'DD/MM/YYYY')
          WHEN str_date ~~ '%-%'
             THEN to_date(str_date, 'DD-Mon-YYYY')
           -- more cases?
          ELSE ???
          END AS date_col
   FROM   tmp;

   -- DROP TABLE tmp;  -- optional; dropped at end of session automatically
   ```

Answer (score 1):

I agree with Erwin, but I would try create database function (PL/pgSQL, PL/Python or other language) that can convert various date strings into `date`. In Erwins answer you can see `WHEN ... THEN` and you can use it. Such function will be easier to test and maintain.