# Date and number formatting

Tags: mysql, postgresql, date, datetime, number-formatting

I know there some functions for date/time and number formatting but is there a way to store and read date and number columns with a custom format?

Ex.:

In my country **DD/MM/YYYY** is a common date format but if I want to store it in a *mysql* or *postgres* database I must store it as **YYYY-MM-DD**.

I've read about some configuration directives in *postgresql* that permits storing dates / numbers in specifc formats.

I think it would be a lot faster to store and read these values without need of conversion routines.

Comment: What RDMS are you actually using? MySQL or PostgreSQL?

Comment: Both. Its a multidatabase project I just started...

Comment: Please handle this at the outer edges of your application. You'll have a much better time if you always speak to the database using sensible ISO 8601 formats. Time and date handling is complicated enough without mashing ambiguous and locale-specific formats into the mix.

Comment: "*that permits storing dates / numbers in specifc formats*" - DATEs do ***NOT*** have "a format". A column defined as `DATE` stores the date value in a binary way (e.g. a numeric value). There is ***NO*** "format" attached to that. Any format you see for those columns is applied by the application (e.g. the SQL client) that _displays_ the data in those columns. Store your dates in columns defined as `DATE` and do the formatting in your application (or use `to_char()` to a apply a format in a SQL statement).

Answer (score 1):

I highly recommend against changing the date format but if you want to do it it's a global variable. Here's an example for MySQL.

```
mysql> show global variables like '%date%';
+-----------------------------------------+-------------------+
| Variable_name                           | Value             |
+-----------------------------------------+-------------------+
| binlog_direct_non_transactional_updates | OFF               |
| date_format                             | %Y-%m-%d          |
| datetime_format                         | %Y-%m-%d %H:%i:%s |
| log_slave_updates                       | OFF               |
| low_priority_updates                    | OFF               |
| query_cache_wlock_invalidate            | OFF               |
| sql_safe_updates                        | OFF               |
+-----------------------------------------+-------------------+
7 rows in set (0.00 sec)
```

so you'll want to set date_format and datetime_format to the desired format. i.e.

This is for the server

```
set global variable date_format = '%d-%m-%Y'; 
set global variable datetime_format = '%d-%m-%Y %H:%i:%s';
```

This is on the client

```
set date_format = '%d-%m-%Y'; 
set datetime_format = '%d-%m-%Y %H:%i:%s';
```

Comment: Hi. Thanks for your answer. Why youl'd say you "highly recommend" changing these variables?

Comment: I wouldn't expect every developer to write code to check date format in their applications so if you're writing the code yourself then you might be ok, if you're working with a third party application you might get undesired results. Sticking with the system standard is usually safest.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe this link will help you:

[How do I alter the date format in Postgres?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6123484/how-do-i-alter-the-date-format-in-postgres)

or this one:

[How to convert date strings to timestamp without knowing the date format](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8130594/postgresql-how-to-convert-string-date-to-timestamp-without-knowing-the-date-form/8130748#8130748)